# How to store json in django mysql database by using python?

Tags: python, mysql, django, json

**Story BackGround:**

I want to store json object in django mysql database by using python programming language.
But I got an error.

**Configuration:**

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04 64bits
- Program language: python
- Framework: django
- database: mysql
- objects need to be store: json

**Code Reference:**

```
json_objects={ u'name': u'REF_1', u'text': u'it is apple', u'time': u'20131210T120039Z'}
```

**Code:**

--> models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Messages(models.Model):
        id           = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        received     = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
        name         = models.TextField()
        data         = models.TextField()
        text         = models.TextField()
        word         = models.TextField()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.text
```

--> views.py

```
from threechannels.models import Messages
data_send_to_db=Messages.objects.create(received=datetime.strptime(json_objects["time"], "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ"),name=json_objects_post["name"],data=json_objects_dumps,text=json_objects["text"],word=related_words_hits)
```

**The error I got:**

DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'")

If I change the json_objects as objects=json.dumps(json_objects), I got another error which is: string indices must be a integer not a string. I think json_objects_post["name"] will cause this problem.

Any Tips???
Thank you so much.

Comment: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/json-fields/

Comment: is your database schema up to date? (have you run syncdb since you added the data field) ?

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems your json_objects is a simple python dictionary. So this is a valid operation:

```
received=datetime.strptime(json_objects["time"], "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
```

But this one is not:

```
name=json_objects_post["name"]
```

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with the "_post" but you can use the python dictionary the way it is supposed to be used as:

```
name=json_objects["name"]
```

Also for the other fields:

```
data=json_objects
```

or

```
data=json.dumps(json_objects)
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

**The original code:**

```
data_send_to_db=Messages.objects.create(received=datetime.strptime(json_objects["time"], "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ"),name=json_objects_post["name"],data=json_objects_dumps,text=json_objects["text"],word=related_words_hits)
```

**Changes:**

```
data_send_to_db=Messages(received=datetime.strptime(json_objects["time"], "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ"),name=json_objects_post["name"],data=json_objects_dumps,text=json_objects["text"],word=related_words_hits)
```

And It works......